# Kotlin Spring Session concurrent session control on already defined Security config

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-jdbc, spring-session

This is a repost from the Github issues page.

Confused on why there are no behavior changes when adding the concurrency session control with Spring session with this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#spring-security-concurrent-sessions)

#### Versions:

- Spring Security **5.2.1.RELEASE**
- Spring Session-JDBC **2.2.0.RELEASE**
- Spring Boot **2.2.4.RELEASE**

Code snippets from our code:

`SecurityConfig.kt`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("auth")
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig<S: Session> : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
     //<some-code-here>
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var sessionRepository: FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<S>

override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        /*
            TODO  enforce requiring application/json content type everywhere (apparently except file upload)
        */

        val publicPaths = arrayOf(
            "/api/v1/centralPortal/current/forgot-password",
            "/api/v1/centralPortal/current/reset-password/*",
            "/api/v1/centralPortal/current/onboard/*",
            "/login",
            "/api/v1/public/**" // CSP reporting is there, needs CSRF disabled
        )

        val filter = JsonLoginFilter(objectMapper, audit, rateLimiter, userManagementService, getAuthMode(env))
        filter.rateLimitPPS = rateLimitPermits / rateLimitSeconds
        filter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sas)
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager())
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler { request, response, _ ->
            val csrfToken = request.getAttribute(CsrfToken::class.java.name) as CsrfToken
            response.addHeader(csrfToken.headerName, csrfToken.token)
        }
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler { request, response, exception ->
            excHandlerAdvice.handleUnauthenticated(request, response, exception, filter.obtainRetries()) }

        http
            .cors().and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .rememberMe().disable()
            .headers()
                // do custom handling of the X-Frame-Options header because some pages need to be iframed
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .addHeaderWriter(ConfigurableFrameOptionsHeaderWriter("/assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html", "/ws/frame.html"))
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .ignoringAntMatchers(*publicPaths)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/manifest.json", "/manifest.webmanifest").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index.js", "/main.js", "/vendor.js", "/service-worker.js", "/workbox-v*/workbox-sw.js", "/precache.*.js", "/*.ico", "/ui/**", "/index.html").permitAll()
                .regexMatchers("^/\\w\\w/ui/.*$").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**/*.webp", "/assets/**/*.png", "/assets/**/*.jpg", "/assets/**/*.svg", "/assets/**/*.gif").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**/*.woff", "/assets/**/*.woff2", "/assets/**/*.ttf", "/assets/**/*.eot").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**/*.css").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(*publicPaths).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/img/logo.png").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler { request, response, accessDeniedException -> excHandlerAdvice.handleAccessDenied(request, response, accessDeniedException) }
                .authenticationEntryPoint { request, response, authException -> excHandlerAdvice.handleUnauthenticated(request, response, authException) }
                .and()
            .addFilter(filter)
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessHandler { request, response, auth -> Unit } // don't redirect
                .and()

        http.headers()
            .cacheControl().disable()
            .addHeaderWriter(CacheControlWriterWithWorkaround())

        // Concurrency control code
        http.sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
    }

    private fun sessionRegistry(): SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<S> {
        return SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(this.sessionRepository)
    }
}
```

JsonLoginFilter.kt

```
data class UserLogin(val username: String, val password: String)

class JsonLoginFilter(private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper, val audit: AuditService?, val rateLimiter: RateLimiterAspect, val userManagementService: UserManagementService?, val authMode: AuthMode) : UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {

    var rateLimitPPS: Double = 1 / 2.0 // rate limiter permits per second default value

    private var _parsed: UserLogin? = null
    private val log = loggerFor<JsonLoginFilter>()

    fun parsedLogin(request: HttpServletRequest): UserLogin {
        val body = request.inputStream
        return objectMapper.readValue(body, UserLogin::class.java)
    }

    private fun loginAttempt(success: Boolean) {
        log.info("Login attempt username=${_parsed?.username} success=$success")
        if (success) {
            resetRetries()
        }
        audit?.eventWithPrincipal(
                AuditObjectCategory.USERS,
                "User",
                _parsed?.username,
                if (success) OtherActions.USER_LOGIN else OtherActions.USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
                _parsed?.username
        )
    }

    override fun attemptAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse?): Authentication {
        try {
            rateLimiter.rateLimit(request, "login", rateLimitPPS)
            _parsed = parsedLogin(request)
            val authResult = super.attemptAuthentication(request, response)
            loginAttempt(authResult != null)
            return authResult
        } catch (e: RateLimiterException) {
            throw e
        } catch (ex: AuthenticationException) {
            loginAttempt(false)
            if (authMode == AuthMode.BUILTIN) userManagementService?.checkUserRetries(_parsed!!.username)
            throw ex
        }
    }

    fun obtainRetries(): Int? {
        return if (authMode == AuthMode.BUILTIN) userManagementService?.getUserRetries(_parsed!!.username) else 0
    }

    fun resetRetries() {
        if (authMode == AuthMode.BUILTIN) {
            userManagementService?.resetUserRetries(_parsed!!.username)
        }
    }

    override fun obtainPassword(request: HttpServletRequest): String {
        return _parsed!!.password
    }

    override fun obtainUsername(request: HttpServletRequest): String {
        return _parsed!!.username
    }
}
```

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
```

So my *expected* behavior based on the code and the documentation would be when there is current login user then another user logs in into another browser, it should prevent the login with `maxSessionPreventsLogin(true)`.

So the *actual* behavior on the code above is that 2 browser with the same user can login, which I didn't expect, since I followed the docs. I'm not really sure if I am missing something, as this is my first time I am encountering Spring Session and Spring Security. Please also take note that the sessions are stored in a DB rather than in-memory.

I would really love if someone can point me to the steps of the correct Spring session configuration, or maybe the documentation should have a precursor on what to configure before doing this, or what when is not an applicable approach.

Thanks

Comment: Where does `JsonLoginFilter` come from? Without the additional filter, I was able to get the code to work as expected. You may want to try removing that filter and see if the problem persists. It will help narrow down the source of the issue.

Comment: @Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana Great idea, I will try to debug from there, I also edited the question above and added JsonLoginFilter code.

Comment: The JsonLoginFilter is required for our custom authentication, this extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana

Comment: I see you are setting `filter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sas)`. The `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` is what holds the information that you set in `.sessionManagement()`. If you are overriding it, then it will not longer have access to `maximumSessions` and `maxSessionsPreventsLogin`.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Thanks, the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` is currently set as `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy` currently this is beyond my knowledge of spring(started 3 weeks ago), since this was already in our security config I thinking this might me plug n play. Anyway I will try to remove `.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy` and see if does something. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana removed `filter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sas)` still can login on 2 different browsers with same user, which I expected that the 2nd login would have been prevented.

Comment: Is it needed to set the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` to `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy`

Comment: ? @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana

Comment: Could you confirm 2 things that may help with debugging? Firstly, I see the profile is set to `auth`. Can you confirm that that is the profile you are running on and that this is the configuration class that is being used? Secondly, could you confirm whether the `JsonLoginFilter` is being called?

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana for both questions, the answer is yes. The application already tested the components you mentioned, it was just now that there was a requirement to add `concurrent session management` and since we already have spring session, we used the documentation to configure this. Are you available in `spring-session` gitter?

Comment: Sure, we can continue the conversation on gitter.